# How does Entity Framework (6.1.3) name ICollections?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We update our database first, and have 3 tables:

Zoo_Keeper

Zoo_Mammal

Zoo_Reptile

(names changed for simplicity!)

A Keeper can have many Mammals.

A Keeper can have many Reptiles.

A foreign key on Zoo_Mammal links to Zoo_Keeper.

A foreign key on Zoo_Reptile links to Zoo_Keeper.

In EntityFramework we use the 'Update Model from Database' functionality, and our Zoo_Keeper auto generated class looks like this:

```
namespace ZooApp.DataAccess.EntityDataModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Zoo_Keeper
    {
        public Zoo_Keeper()
        {
            this.Mammals = new HashSet<Zoo_Mammal>();
            this.Zoo_Reptile = new HashSet<Zoo_Reptile>();
        }

        //some properties

        public virtual ICollection<Zoo_Mammal> Mammals { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Zoo_Reptile> Zoo_Reptile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How does EF come up with the names for the ICollections? (Mammals, Zoo_Reptile)

We're confused as to why one has stripped the 'Zoo' prefix, but the other hasn't. What is it about our database which is causing EF to name relationships differently?

We've checked the FK names, but these both look consistent:

FK_Zoo_Mammal_Zoo_Keeper

FK_Zoo_Reptile_Zoo_Keeper

Comment: What are the names of the columns in the tables?

Comment: KeeperID, MammalID, ReptileID (PKs), KeeperID, KeeperID (FKs)

Answer (score 0):

Turns these custom names had been configured in the .edmx file using the NavigationProperty tag:

```
<EntityType Name="Zoo_Keeper">
...
<NavigationProperty Name="Mammals" Relationship="Self.FK_Zoo_Mammal_Zoo_Keeper" FromRole="Zoo_Keeper" ToRole="Zoo_Mammal" />
</EntityType>
```